# Как отключить репозиторий от vs code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Подключил репозиторий GitHub к vscode, но vscode просит (имеется в виду значок слева, с ожидающимися изменениями), чтобы я отправил изменения в репозиторий. Как отключить это? Хочу закончить проект полностью и потом отправить. Постоянно высвечивается и отвлекает, нагружает пк. Пошарился в инете, ничего не нашел.

Comment: Прям так и нагружает? :) Делайте коммиты без пуша к репозиторий, как закончите, отправите все сразу, можете слить все коммиты в один перед отправкой. Git придуман чтобы облегчить жизнь, а не чтобы отвлекать и нагружать.

Comment: если "ожидающие изменения" нагружают комп, то либо Вы что то не договариваете, либо не понимаете, что происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете полностью "выпилится из GIT", просто зайдя в папку и удалив из её корня скрытый каталог `.git`. Это довольно радикальный способ: Вы просто отказываетесь от использования системы контроля версий.

Можно сделать этот способ "мягче": переместить эту папку в безопасное место, некоторое время поработать без раздражающих предложений VS Code. Когда всё готово - копируете папку обратно, перезапускаете VS Code, она говорит "ой, сколько изменений!" - и уже можно закоммитить их и потом запушить.

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой на панели и убери галочку с Source Control. Больше не будет "*Постоянно высвечивается и отвлекает, нагружает пк*".